# After upgrading vapor-cli, Laravel vapor deploy still fails "you are using an outdated version of Vapor CLI"

Tags: docker, deployment, laravel-vapor, vapor-cli

i'm trying to deploy my laravel vapor application from my computer, as I always do. But yesterday a got an error:

*Whoops! There were some problems with your request.
"You are using an outdated version of Vapor CLI. Please update to the latest version before deploying."*

So I updated laravel/vapor-cli from 1.43 to 1.44 (latest now)
But the deployment still fails at the same point.
Tried: composer dump-autoload, composer remove vapor-cli and require again (updated) but always fails at the same point.

I use **docker runtime**.

The deployment builds the project ok

[deploy ok till here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyvrs.png)

but fails "pushing container image"

```
==> Pushing Container Image
The push refers to repository [8zzzz4f6h3dz.dkr.ecr.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/myapp-vapor]
5485100749ee: Preparing
2042d777ff6d: Preparing
...
bfd1896d-0d92-4b72-a8f8-fde92c3ee108: digest: sha256:823b239d4445957e8f7bff478e86c18b023c4d5f7edf9c7339c2e532e67c4780 size: 5557


Whoops! There were some problems with your request.

- You are using an outdated version of Vapor CLI. Please update to the latest version before deploying.
```

[deployment message error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upfKT.png)

Any ideas on how to solve this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Laravel Vapor documentation says [here](https://docs.vapor.build/1.0/introduction.html#installing-the-vapor-cli)

I updated the "local" vapor-cli package.

Once I also updated the "global" package, the deployment finished successfully.

```
composer global require laravel/vapor-cli --update-with-dependencies
```

[image: Laravel vapor documentation]